# Magento2: How to get tax rate and tax percent from product

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-class

How can I get tax rate and tax percent from a product in magento2?
In magento1 we use below code:

```
        $taxClassId = $item->getData("tax_class_id");
        $taxClasses = Mage::helper("core")->jsonDecode(Mage::helper("tax")->getAllRatesByProductClass());
        $taxRate = $taxClasses["value_" . $taxClassId];
        $taxAmount = (($item->getQty() * $itemPrice * $taxRate) / 100);
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is not a API, but much more flexible approach for getting tax rate that I had to use once:

```
    // SETTING DEFAULT VALUES FOR CALCULATION EXAMPLE

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config */
    $countryCode = $config->getValue(\Magento\Shipping\Model\Config::XML_PATH_ORIGIN_COUNTRY_ID);
    $customerTaxClassId = $config->getValue('tax/classes/default_customer_tax_class');

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
    $productTaxClassId = $product->getData('tax_class_id');

    // THE ACTUAL CALCULATION CALL

    /** @var \Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation $taxCalculation */
    $rate = $taxCalculation->getRate(
        new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'country_id' => $countryCode,
                'customer_class_id' => $customerTaxClassId,
                'product_class_id' => $productTaxClassId
            ]
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 5):

I achieved getting tax rates by using *\Magento\Tax\Api\TaxCalculationInterface*:

```
    $rate = $this->taxCalculation->getCalculatedRate($productTaxClassId, $customerId, $storeId);
```

Comment: is it working for guest customer?  In my case it's not working. getting tax rate 0.

Comment: If you go through the Implementation of  \Magento\Tax\Api\TaxCalculationInterface (in my case  Magento\Tax\Model\TaxCalculation) you can find a fallback for guests if $customerId is missing

Comment: page cache doesn't allow customerId in blocks or templates

Comment: @obscure you are right. But in this case customerId might be null. If it's null it is based on store address and default customer tax class current store. 

If you want to get the tax rate by current customer group u might try following:
-Get TaxClassId by current group id (served by HTTP Context)
- Call TaxCalculation::getRateRequest
- Finally call Calculation::getRate